# How to add a simple horizontal line to mplfinance plot?

Tags: python, plot, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

I know it may sound too simple but it got me stuck!
I have a candle stick chart using fplt and I simply want to add a horizontal line to it but not sure how!

```py
ax = fplt.plot(
                result,
                type='candle',
                style = 'charles',
                title='whatever!',
                ylabel='anything',figsize=(24,8)
            )
```

this creates my candle chart pretty well and nice as I wanted!
but then I use `ax.axhline(...)` but gives me error  or I use `ax.plt(x_coordinates,y_coordinates)` but again error:
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'plt'`

can someone please make my life easier?! I just want to add a horizontal line here!
thanks

Comment: As a general rule, you should indicate in SO questions what you have done to try to solve your question.   You have not indicate that you have tried anything.  Simply googling "mplfinance horizontal line" will show you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With mplfinance, this is as simple as reading the [**mplfinance documentation**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#contents-and-tutorials), specifically the section titled **[Trends, Support, Resistance, and Trading Lines](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb)**

You can see there this is as simple as using the `hlines` kwarg:

Also, `mpf.plot()` (or as you have unconventionally written, `fplt.plot()`) returns None, *unless you set kwarg* `returnfig=True`, but for what you want to do, there is *no reason* to [access the Figure or Axes objects](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects).

hth

Answer (score 1):

Briefly reading the intro https://pypi.org/project/finplot/ it looks like `fplt.plot` returns None (which you then assign to `ax`) and you should get the axis from `fplt.create_plot()`

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, fplt is mplfinance module not finplot. For some reason I have problems installing finplot (issues with the version and dll file ...)